# Can threads share data when they reside in two different CPUs?

Tags: multithreading

From what i learnt in class, two of the main reasons why we want to use thread are:

. Parallelization

. They can share the same global address space

I assume that the reason why we like it that they share data is because we dont have to clear the cache table every time we running different thread from the same process.

My question is, in order to have parallelization, threads have to be run in different CPU, then how do they share data when CPUs dont share cache table? Is my assumption wrong? or we can only have one of the property listed above at a time? thank you.

Comment: Your question makes a lot of assumptions.  A thread is just a thread.  It has the same privileges as any other thread.  A cache is not required to run a thread, nor is dedicating a cpu core required.

Comment: Do distinguish multi-core processors from multi-processor machines.  The latter are normally configured in a numa architecture, giving each processor its own memory bus.  There's an interconnect but it is a bottleneck.  You'd need a special library to take advantage of it, they typically use explicit message passing.  I think, I don't get to play much with big iron.  The [mpi] tag at SO covers it.